# Implementing a WPF custom property to semantically group checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

Could any of the WPF gurus here point me in the right direction of what it would take to implement a system whereby checkboxes that belong to some "group" have certain behaviors, like enforcing that at least one checkbox is left selected.

By "point to the right direction" I mean a high level instructions, not code (of course, if you have code example, it's even better).

Here's an example of how ideally it'd work:

```
<checkbox custom:AtLeastOneGroupName="group1" isChecked={Binding PropA}>First</checkbox>
<checkbox custom:AtLeastOneGroupName="group1" isChecked={Binding PropB}>Seccond</checkbox>
```

Comment: Simply use a dependency property like in http://blog.bradcunningham.net/2009/09/grouping-and-checkboxes-in-wpf.html